# Alignment in matrix (bmatrix)

Tags: align, matrices

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
    \begin{matrix}
    s
    & = & [ &
    s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5
    & ]^T \\
    & = & [ &
        \phi_1+ABCD   &
        \phi_2+ABCD   &
        \tau_{p3}+ABCD&
        \mu_p+ABCD    &
        \mu_p^2+ABCD  &
    ]^T
    \end{matrix}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to use this type of alignment. But notice that the full stop sign `.` is at the wrong place.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!!

Updated:

Sorry if I was not clear and may have caused some confusion.
I would hope to align the elements in the cells like the updated matrix.
A lot of the suggested approach would not align in such way.

[image: Probably exaggerated, but hope to make my point of what I want to achieve.]

Comment: Why are you inserting the `s` and equal sign inside the matrix?

Comment: This makes more sense: `\begin{align*}
    s&= \begin{bmatrix}
    s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 \end{bmatrix}^T \\
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
        \phi_1   &
        \phi_2   &
        \tau_{p3}&
        \mu_p    &
        \mu_p^2  &
        \end{bmatrix}^T.
\end{align*}
`

Comment: Well, move the period `]^T.` inside the matrix.

Comment: don't use `equation` for multi-line equations use `align` and don't use `matrix` for aligning whole equations just use it for making matrices, or here you can use `bmatrix` as  sigur suggests.

Comment: @Sigur That's what I initially used. However, the problem with that is, if the elements in the second line is wider than those in the first line, the first `bmatrix` will be much smaller than the second `bmatrix`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the alignment between the columns, use an `array`, with some enhancement:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r<{{}} @{}r@{\,} *{5}{c} @{\,}l@{}}
s = & [ & s_1       & s_2       & s_3          & s_4      & s_5     & ]^T \\[1ex]
  = & [ & \phi_1^{} & \phi_2^{} & \tau_{p3}^{} & \mu_p^{} & \mu_p^2 & ]^T.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a one off application that's good; if several similar displays are needed, you can define an environment and a command to ease the input:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{alignedrows}[1]
 {\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r<{{}} @{}r@{\,} *{#1}{c} @{\,}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}}
\newcommand{\arow}[2]{%
  #1 & [ & #2 & ]^T %
}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
\begin{alignedrows}{5}
\arow{s=}{ s_1       & s_2       & s_3          & s_4      & s_5     } \\[1ex]
\arow{ =}{ \phi_1^{} & \phi_2^{} & \tau_{p3}^{} & \mu_p^{} & \mu_p^2 }.
\end{alignedrows}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: This does seem like a nice solution. The only downside was that it seems a lot of `{@{} >{{}}r<{{}} @{}r@{\,} *{5}{c} @{\,}l@{}}` to read. And I have to adjust `*{5}{c}` for a general use.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu No problem! `;-)` Just define a suitable environment and a command.

Comment: I do appreciate the solution. But I don't think it is easier if I have to use `\phi_1^{}` instead of just `\phi_1` ? Is the `{}` adjusting for empty spaces?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu That's a refinement in order to have the subscripts at the same relative height, it has nothing to do with the general problem.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Don't use `equation` for multi-line equations use `align` and don't use `matrix` for aligning whole equations just use it for making matrices, or here you can use `bmatrix` as  sigur suggests.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
\begin{aligned}
s&=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5
    \end{bmatrix}^T \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
        \phi_1   &
        \phi_2   &
        \tau_{p3}&
        \mu_p    &
        \mu_p^2  
    \end{bmatrix}^T
    \text{.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you want alignment of the entries using a single alignment spoils the structure of the expression have an environment for each matrix, so instead I would use separate alignments but with widths forced equal:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
\begin{aligned}
s&=
    (\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1.2em}<{$}}@{}}
    s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5
    \end{array})^T \\
 &= (\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1.2em}<{$}}@{}}
        \phi_1   &
        \phi_2   &
        \tau_{p3}&
        \mu_p    &
        \mu_p^2  
    \end{array})^T
    \text{.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice idea, except the elements inside the matrices aren't lined up together as i think is wanted.  actually, i think that using `bmatrix` is the wrong approach here in any event.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That was exactly why I did not use `bmatrix` in this example. The first line will be smaller than the second line.

Comment: +1 for the `\text{.}`. Nice!

Comment: Thanks for the `\text{.}`. That solved one big problem with my current code!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu -- the "bmatrix" in the question title is misleading them.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see. Sorry. Because initially, I was hoping to achieve this using `bmatrix`. But I failed. How should I rephrase this title then?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu -- i think you can just remove that from the title.  the (newly updated) visual makes it clear enough that you want to have brackets around each line.  (and also makes it more clear that the elements are to be aligned.  nice.)

Comment: @ChenStatsYu see update with entries in each matrix aligned

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What's the point of `\text{.}`? I don't see any difference from what I don't put the full stop in text mode.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg logical purity mostly: the full stop is part of the sentence not part of the mathematics. They are actually from different fonts although probably have identical definition in computer modern, but could potentially have a visible difference if your math font is not an exact match for the text font.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution along the lines @Sigur suggested. (I was working on it while he was commenting.)

[image]

To get the inner alignment you wanted I hard coded some whitespace. If you need to do this often you'll need a more elegant solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is

\begin{align}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
s & = \begin{bmatrix}
        & s_1 & s_2 \  & s_3 \  & s_4 & s_5 &
       \end{bmatrix}^T \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
        &
        \phi_1   &
        \phi_2   &
        \tau_{p3}&
        \mu_p    &
        \mu_p^2  &
     \end{bmatrix}^T \quad . \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But as noticed, I need a more general approach to achieve the inner alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \vect { s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
    { \chen_v_vector:n { #2 } }
    { \chen_h_vector:n { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \chen_h_vector:n { \chen_vector_aux:nn { &  } }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \chen_v_vector:n { \chen_vector_aux:nn { \\ } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chen_vector_aux:nn #1 #2
 {
  \begin { bmatrix }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \end { bmatrix }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The reparameterisation is
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:linear_ssK3}
\begin{split}
  s &= \vect{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5}^T \\[1ex]
    &= \vect{\phi_1,\phi_2,\tau_{p3},\mu_p,\mu_p^2}^T.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With that new command I defined, `\vect` you can easily input matrix vectors: `\vect{a,b,c}` will make an horizontal array with three entries (`a`, `b`, `c`, they are separated by commas), and with `\vect*{a,b,c}` you will get a *vertical* matrix instead.

Comment: This does not align the s_5 and \mu[p]^2 as I would want them to.

Comment: I wasn't sure from your question that you indeed wanted that, only because egreg wrote an answer. In any case, my idea with this answer was providing an easy way of input for vectors, which may work for you (and someone else) in other cases (I could even include the `^T` as a part of the transposed vector, in case you always write that with “horizontal vectors”).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that I may not have been very clear about this. Please see my updated post (picture). The new example may be a bit exaggerated but it should demonstrate what kind of alignment I hope to achieve.  Not that I always write “horizontal vectors”, but in some cases, the reparameterisation are short, like the original MWE, I hope to save some space using such alignment by making the vectors horizontal.

Comment: Okey, okey. I already understood. This *doesn't* answer that question, however I leave it here, since I think it might be useful to others (even to you, in other cases where you don't need such alignment).